# Models vs Views in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

From couple of days, I have started working/learning the [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). I have read documentation on their site. I have also read few tutorials available [here](http://backbonetutorials.com/).

As per my understanding below are few major differences between Views and Models.

- Only view has 'el'. *Why it is not there in Model ?*
- Only Models have 'get','set', 'save' methods.
- Only Models have functions like fetch, save, destroy, validate
  methods,clear,has.

According Hello World examples [here](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/), View can also do the things Models can do.

- Both have extend, render, initializer, getter setter methods.
- Both can be converted into JSON using toJSON.

hence, I am confused between Models and Views. When to use each one ?

my question is.. *what is practical difference between Models and Views? What are different situations to use Models/Views ? What should be appropriate to use for displaying(render)?*

*Can anyone good @ Backbone.js explain with practical scenario* ?

Your help will make my understanding much clear.

Comment: a very nice resource to backbone is http://backbonetutorials.com/ it is very helpful when you are beginning to play with the framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model and Views are not Backbone terms. You can read about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm first.
Model contain data and logic for data manipulations. View describes how this data should be displayed.
Hence only View have 'el' - because this it is used while displaying data.
Getters and setters are in model according to MVC paradigm.